# Random selection balls into two groups and show they did not change in two trials

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, random

I have $10$ balls which are numbered from $1$ to $10$. Randomly select (uniform) these balls into two groups (number of balls in two groups is different). Then compute the mean value of numbers on these balls
$$m_i=\frac {\text{total number on balls in group $i$}}{\text{total balls in group $i$}}$$
At the fist trial, I saw that $m_1=m_2$. Then I mixed these balls and classified again into two groups. Note that, the number balls in each group of this trials may be same or different will first trial.

At this trail, I saw that $m_1$ still equals $m_2$. At that sense, Could I conclude that these balls in two group are similar in two trials?

Comment: Not clear what the question is here.  It is not true that $m_1=m_2$ always, though of course it's possible.  Can't do it with $5$ in each...but $\{10,6,4,2\}$ vs. $\{9,8,7,5,3,1\}$ works.  Looks fairly improbable that you'd get an exact match. But other combinations are possible.

Comment: In my question, I just assume that in two trials, I obtained same results  $m_1=m_2$ for both trails. Is is true if I said that these balls in two set did not change

Comment: My boxes sum to $22$ and $33$.  $\frac {22}{4}=5.5=\frac {33}{6}$. And no, the balls don't have to match.  Taking $\{9,6,4,3\}$ as the box of four works as well, and there are lots of other combinations.

Comment: Thanks . I got it

Comment: You could also have collections of two and eight, you just need the two to sum to $11$.  Thus $\{6,5\}$ and $\{10,9,8,7,4,3,2,1\}$ works.

Comment: Could you suggest to me the condition to obtain the result that elements in two group won't change?

Comment: Probably requiring that the variances also match gets it done...haven't checked that.